# How can I make a button that "runs away" from the cursor?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to write code that will keep moving a button when the user hovers over it with their mouse (so it can never actually be clicked)

I am using the "style.left" in order to determine the new button location

Here is the function I wrote that doesn't work as I would like it to:

```
document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("mouseenter", run);
    function run() {
        var posLeft = 500 ;
        if (posLeft > 450) {
             document.getElementById("button5").style.left = posLeft + "px"; 
                posLeft +=150;
    }
        else if (posLeft >= 800) { 
                    posLeft = 200;
                    document.getElementById("button5").style.left = posLeft +"px"};
    };
```

I expected the button to keep moving: as long as posLeft is smaller than 800px I want it to move to the right of the screen, and once it passes that threshold I want ti  to reset to 200px. Instead it only jumps to the right once and does nothing else.

Comment: 1990's all over again. lol

Comment: `var posLeft = 500 ;` <-- well why is it set to 500 each time? You need to define that outside

Comment: Buttons have gotten smarter since 1995 and no longer experience fear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `posLeft` declared in the wrong scope. It should be declared *alongside* `run`, not inside it. Because it's inside it, you get a new `posLeft` equal to 500 every time `run` runs.

Alternately, you could read the value from the element (which is probably a better idea).

Also note that you have your two conditions reversed. You have

```
if (posLeft > 450) {
    // ...
} else if (posLeft >= 800) {
    // ...
}
```

The second condition will never be true, because the first is always true and is tested beforehand. Just reverse them.

So, something along the lines of:

```js
document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("mouseenter", run);
function run() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("button5");
    if (!btn.style.left) {
        // Default to 500 to start
        btn.style.left = "500px";
    } else {
        var posLeft = parseInt(btn.style.left); // parseInt ignores the px on the end
        if (posLeft >= 800) {
            btn.style.left = "200px";
        } else if (posLeft > 450) {
            posLeft += 150;
            btn.style.left = (posLeft + 150) + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" style="position: absolute" id="button5" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and works! The one thing I am not understanding from the code you wrote is the !btn.style.left : what does the ! before the variable name mean/do?

Comment: @tzvik15 - It's the negation operator. It takes its operand, coerces it to a boolean value, and then negates that value. By default, the button won't have any inline `left` style, so `btn.style.left` will be `""`, which coerces to `false`. So `if (!btn.style.left)` checks to see if `btn.style.left` has not been set yet.